# How to detect which checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to use checkboxes, but there's no submit button-- it needs to have an effect on the page the user is already on, the same page that contains the checkboxes.

Essentially, I have ~10 checkbox elements. The user selects a certain number of them, then clicks a button element. When they click that element, I need to detect which checkboxes have been checked. What's the best way to do that with the shortest amount of code?

Comment: do you use jquery or other js lib ? or you need that done in  plan javascript code ? in jquery : `$('selectorx :checked')` is shortest one

Comment: Aesthete got it! I didn't care, could be either. Whatever was fastest, which is usually jQuery.

Comment: The question is tagged as `jquery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have all your checkboxes share the same class.

```
var allChecked = $(".checkBoxClass:checked");
```

This will return a list of checked checkboxes in the class `checkBoxClass`. Now you can iterate each element and operate on them.

```
for(var i=0; i<allChecked.length; i++) {    
  console.log("Checkbox " + $(allChecked[i]).val().toString() + " is checked");
}
```

Comment: jQuery is godly. This is great. For some reason I'd been worried about this.

Comment: This will NOT work. There is a space between the class name and the checked attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="one"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="two"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="three"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Check"/>   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(){
            var chkArr = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
            var notChecked='';
            for(var i=0;i<chkArr.length;i++){
                if(!chkArr[i].checked)
                    notChecked += chkArr[i].value
            }
            if(notChecked.length)
                alert(notChecked);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: now a days poeple don't understand plan-js :) , if you put full answer in plan-js that will be great

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work:

```
$('input:checked');

$('input:checkbox:checked');

$('input:checkbox').filter(':checked');
```